# Is it expensive to import a module just for its type declarations?

Tags: typescript

Instead of declaring variables to be of type `any`, I would like to import, for example `express`, to be able to declare a variable to be of, for example, type `express.Response`.

Is this a recommended move?

Answer (score 1):

As long as none of the imports are used in expressions, the module import will be elided in emitted code so there is no run-time penalty for this. If you just use the imports in type annotations these will not count as being used in expressions.

See the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit) for more information

Comment: That being said, why not just use the .d.ts declaration file?

Comment: It depends how the module is defined, if it uses exports directly on the types you might not be able to just `///` the definition file.

Comment: In the case of `express` I believe it’s enough to just have the typings file somewhere in your projec folder.

Comment: @Kokodoko just tried it .. doesn't seem to work for express. Either way the question was in general about importing types, express was just an example.